# Secure microservices from another microservice in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have 2 microservices, one if them is responsible of authorization and authentication using JWT and Spring Security, i have auth service, user repo, security configs and so on...
I want to secure the other microservice using this one, i have searched a lot and got confused, some tutorials and examples are using zuul and eureka, some use OAuth 2.0 without jwt, is it possible to use jwt and just make the first microservice as an "Authorization server" ?

When the client want to access the "secured endpoints" from Microservice 2, it should verify the token using Microservice 1
I want an easy way to do that and any help or useful links will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do your clients access your microservices? If you want to prevent access to microservices2 (the *target service*) without previous authentication on microservices1 (the *auth service*) then you need to route calls to the target service through something that verifies that authentication has happened with the *auth service*.

This could be done several ways ... in a proxy app, by adding proxy functionality to the *auth service* itself, by network layers/tools like istio, etc. How and where you will be deploying your applications will have an impact on your solution.

Comment: With this way, i need then to use RestTemplate, send a request to auth service and check if the token is valid or not